# Remove MFMailComposeViewController padding around HTML email?

Tags: ios, html-email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

When creating a `MFMailComposeViewController` and setting the message body to be HTML, I end up with margins around the provided markup. It looks as though `MFMailComposeViewController` is taking the HTML passed to `setMessageBody:isHTML:` and sticking it inside a container, which includes padding on all sides and the iPhone email signature on the bottom.

Is there anyway to get rid of this padding?